# How to send a signal to the usb pins through android application..?

Tags: android, usb

I want to send signal or some current in programmatic way through my application.

I have gone through USB host and accessory mode of the android but its not usefull.

I am restricted to android 2.3.4 and I have OTG cable.

I have a LED board which represents 4 pins of the usb, I want to send signal to any one of the pin, throuh my application.

After a lot of googling, I am posting this question here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry for my brevity, but: That is *not* possible. Period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, but what you CAN do is communicate with another device with bluetooth or wifi and establish a connection with a proper software that drives the usb port.